# Add a second add to cart button on Woocommerce with the Price List

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

I want to add a second add to cart button near the principal add to cart in my product page.

In this moment I have the principal add to cart button (that add product to cart with the sale price). So I want to add a second add to cart called 'Add to cart with price list' (that add product to cart with the price list and not the sale price).

How do I do this?

I found this code, but how do I set the list price?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_button_after_product_summary', 30 );

function custom_button_after_product_summary() {
  global $product;
  echo "<a href='".$product->add_to_cart_url()."'>add to cart</a>";
```

Thank you so much

Comment: **"Editing"** your question, you should clarify the **"with price list"** as it's not understandable. On what type of products? What version of Woocommerce? Why do you tag your question "Javascript" and "shortcode"? … An added item to cart needs only to have one price… multiple item prices are not handled by WC_Cart class.

Comment: Ok. "Fantastic Product" list price: 150€, discount price: 40€. In the product there is the "Add to cart" button that adds the product to the cart with the price of € 40. I would like a "Add to cart without discount" button that adds me the product to the cart with the price of 150 €. I have the latest version of WordPress and version 4.2.6 of Woocommerce.

Comment: **"Edit"** your question please clicking on **"Edit"** linked text after the question tags…

Comment: I have already read all the questions, but there are none that satisfy and solve my problem @LoicTheAztec